# I would convert svg to png using Imagick but turns black shadow around

Tags: php, svg, converters, imagick

I would convert svg to png using Imagick but turns black shadow around. How can I delete it. I am using the following code.

http://imageshack.com/a/img538/9707/Cs5BLb.jpg

```
<?php
$genislik = $_GET["gs"];
$yukseklik = $_GET["ys"];
$renk = $_GET["a"];
$sekil = $_GET["y"];
$boyut = $_GET["z"];
$stl = $_GET["yb"];

if ($stl=="1") { 
$bold = "bold";
} else { 
$bold = "normal";
}    

$im = new Imagick();

$im-> setResolution ($genislik, $yukseklik);

$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1400" height="300">
<text x="0" y="80" style="fill: #'.$renk .'; font-family: monospace; font-size: '.$boyut.'px; font-weight: '.$bold.';">'.$sekil.'</text>  
</svg>';

$im->readImageBlob($svg);
$im->trimImage(0);

$im->setImageFormat("png32");

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $im;
?>
```

scaleImage() shadow fades When I use the code. But the resolution is happening losses.

```
$d = $im->getImageGeometry(); 
$w = $d['width']; 
$h = $d['height'];

$im->scaleImage($w-0.1, $h-0.1);
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug in either the version of ImageMagick you are using, or the library underneath that is doing the SVG rendering. Can you say what versions you're using? Also - in your example code, you really ought to provide values for all the variables, rather than just copying and pasting code that is not a complete self-contained example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention. And I'm sorry inadequate because of my English.
imagick 3.1.2 library installed. I develop this code, design editor.

The link I used to run this library is below.

/yazi.php?y=Katman1&yb=0&a=ff0000&z=20&ys=100&gs=100